# Collect id_token amr claim with OpenIdConnect ClaimsProvider in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I would like to capture the Authentication Method Reference (amr claim) values from the id_token.  I was considering saving this as a PersistedClaim in the session.

> sub                : xxxxxxxx
> ....
> amr                : {pwd, swk, mfa}
> idp                : yyyyyyyy

Because this claim is included in the ID token,  not in the data collected from the userinfo endpoint,  I'm not sure if this is possible with OIDC.

I have tried adding an amr claim type:

```
 <ClaimType Id="amr">
    <DisplayName>Authentication Method Reference</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
      <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="amr" />
    </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
    <UserHelpText>rfc8176</UserHelpText>
  </ClaimType>
```

and an OutputClaim:

```
   <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="amr" PartnerClaimType="amr" />
```

but this isn't returning a fairly opaque:  "AADB2C: An exception has occurred."

1. Is this claim capture from the id_token even possible?
2. If so,  how can I dig into this "AADB2C: An exception has occurred."?

Comment: That claim is information about the token (session) and not part of the user's profile data. That's why you don't get it with the UserInfo endpoint. Why don't just read it from the token? Remember that a JWT is just base-64 encoded.

Comment: I like that approach but I couldn’t find an example of this.  I know how to decode the token  but I don’t know how to get the id_token when using the OIDC provider. 

Could you point me to an example?

Comment: Let me understand a little bit more about the context.
What are you getting after the user is authenticated? How do you hit the user info endpoint without a token (either id_token or access_token)?
You should have already a token

Comment: Azure B2C calls to Okta using OpenIdConnect to authenticate (not OAuth2).   I don't see where I can get the id_token.  I only get output claims (from OIDC user info). 

```
<TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Okta-OIDC-xyz">
          <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="METADATA">https://xyz.okta.com/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
            <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
            <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">openid profile email</Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD B2C doesn’t issue an amr claim like Azure AD does. You need to output this claim at the relevant technical profiles (sign in step, mfa step) and then in the relying party section using a custom policy.

You can troubleshoot your error:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot-with-application-insights

If you want to track the auth type through a federated Idp, then the IdP must be configured to issue a claim that AAD B2C can then ingest using an outputclaim.

Comment: The IDP does issue the claim in the JWT send during the OAuth2 steps,  but I am using an OIDC TechnicalProfile in Azure B2C. 

How can I "reach back" to the OAuth2 stage of the processing if I am using an OIDC profile?

Comment: If the Oauth2 technical profile for your IdP has an output claim for the “amr” claim, then it’s available to any subsequent orchestration step. And to issue it into the AAD B2C token (which is what I think you mean by the OIDC TP), output it in the relyingparty section too. The concepts are covered here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-trust-frameworks

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT, any examples of how to map the amr claim into the claims bag? I've tried a few ways of adding the claim as an output claim in the Oath2 technical profile, but no luck.